# Mysql error Cataloginventory_stock_status does not exist

Tags: magento2, database

Hi i am getting the following error, need help please. using magento 2.4.5
and Xampp

In Mysql.php line 109:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'magento2.cataloginventory_stock_status' doesn't exist in
engine, query was: SHOW INDEXES FROM `cataloginventory_stock_status` WHERE `Non_unique` = 1

In Mysql.php line 90:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'magento2.cataloginventory_stock_status' doesn't exist in
engine

Answer (score 0):

Please run the reindexer,

> bin/magento indexer:reindex

Still, issue persist check the table name of cataloginventory_stock entries and change the website_id to 0 for default stock and do the reindex once.